# Tabbed windows in Texmaker?

Tags: texmaker

Is it possible to have tabbed windows in Texmaker, currently it is a dropdownlist, and can open one windows at one time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texmaker uses the same system than modern editors like xcode, kate, qtcreator which don't use anymore tabs.

The "list of opened files" option of the "View" menu works like tabs : if you click on an item, the editor for the corresponding file is displayed :
[image]